# Google Map API Direction Service steps shows Chinese letters

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using direction services and I get response like the following:
"Head **north** on **Piazza del Duomo** toward **Piazza S. Giovanni/圣若望广场/聖若望廣場**"
I saw this several times for sites in Florence.
For example, between Florence Cathedral and Battistero but there are more.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks,

Amir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a bug(data-defect?).
These chinese characters seem to be a real translation of [Piazza S. Giovanni](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%A3%E8%8B%A5%E6%9C%9B%E5%B9%BF%E5%9C%BA_%28%E4%BD%9B%E7%BD%97%E4%BC%A6%E8%90%A8%29)(of course the translation should not be there).

When I e.g. set the language to german I even get more translations(russian, hebrew,hungarian,greek)

I'm afraid the only thing you can do so far is to send a bug-report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Directions%20API%20-%20Bug